# Distribution or Release for upload app

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

In the Xcode 4.6 build settings, I can't find "Distribution", only "Debug" and "Release".

In order to submit my app to the app store, do I need "Distribution", or is "Release" enough?

Answer (score 1):

Select the Release and than rename it to Distribution from here

[image]

For more info check out this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAdV16nRLp8)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the release configuration for distribution .. or make a duplicate and name it distribution.